# Move and Print script result simultaneously in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a python script which outputs the result like below

```
clean -> 123
add > 242
remove -> 980
add -> 679
clean -> 567
...
...
```

I have 35000 line of result like this.
I would like to move this result and prints it at the same time.

i am using below command

```
python scriptname.py arg1 arg2 > output.txt 2>&1 &
```

With this the result is moving to file only after the script ends.
Please suggest the linux command for this?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to print into file and on the screen at the same time, right? You can use `tee` for that:

```sh
python scriptname.py arg1 arg2 2>&1 | tee output.txt
```

Normally `tee` overwrites the given file with new data. Use `tee -a` to append data to the file instead.

Comment: May mention `tee -a` if the OP need to append to `output.txt` instead of truncating each call. But this seems like what they are after if I understand...

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Updated the answer. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Is there any way to copy this file in a faster way. It is taking very long time to copy the result to output file.

Comment: That might be caused by the output being printed at the same time. Some consoles are very slow in displaying large amounts of text (I myself have to deal with this with WSL and a 4K display).